# Entity Framework IDbCommandInterceptor never sets Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I was looking for a global way to monitor exceptions that EF might throw. Therefor I implemented a IDbCommandInterceptor and use the following code to log the exception to the console.

```
private void LogIfError<TResult>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
  {
     if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(interceptionContext.OriginalException.Message);
     }
  }
```

The methods in the intercepter are hit but the OrignalException is always empty when I for example force a "Sequence contains no elements" using a .Single().
The exception is now being caught by my global exception handler in my application.

What am I missing here? Or is there a better way to globally catch exceptions like this one?

Comment: Can you force a different exception? Finding no record for a `Single` query is no database exception, that's in your program. If you want to record that, you might need another way to log that.

Comment: While debugging a little more and looking at the query being executed I came to the same conclusion. This interceptor isn't going to help me with this problem.